# Не включается компьютер из-за радиатора CPU

Tags: железо

Очень странная вещь происходит. Внезапно потух и перестал включаться компьютер. По нажатию на кнопку питания на полсекунды дергаются кулеры и дальше тишина. Отключал/подключал поочередно всю периферию и пришел к выводу - мешает радиатор ЦП. Если его снять, компьютер включается, на мониторе появляются стандартные сообщения BIOS, и все как обычно, дожидаться загрузки ОС не стал, т.к. процессор все таки без охлаждения. Поменял термопасту, поставил радиатор на место и опять та же ерунда. Снимаю радиатор - работает. Сокет 1150. Собственно сам вопрос: да как так то??? Как может мешать радиатор? Я понимаю может ОЗУ выйти из строя, или БП, или еще что, но не радиатор же. В общем посоветуйте что-нибудь, пожалуйста.

Comment: Была точно такая же ситуация. Как ни странно помогли долгие танцы с бубном. После скупой мужской слезы (образно, конечно) и пары дней валяния себя на кровати и глазения в пустоту (на системник) он чудесным образом включился. А если по делу, то проверьте правильность подключения кулера, у меня такое было еще и после обновления ЦП, материнки и неправильной установки кулера (не до конца дожал лапку, AM2 сокет вроде).

Comment: Попробуйте его сразу нежно установить (корпус на бочек положите), просто приложите кулер, не закрепляя его (и не подключая к CPU FAN), потом закрепите, не подключая. А потом подключите. Посмотрите, на каком из этапов вылетает. Ну и от этого пляшите. Бубен еще никогда не подводил.

Comment: Радиатор или кулер создают проблему? Визуально проверьте ножки на сокете.

Comment: а кто такой «рабоатор»?

Comment: @alexander точно, не такого)) Исправил))

Comment: Проверьте ещё, чтобы не были кондёры вздуты.

Answer (score 4):

Причина оказалась в том, что площадка радиатора слегка выступала за края сокета и задевала ножки конденсатора. Причем эту проблему оказывается знали те, кто собирал этот системник в магазине, т.к. рядом обнаружился кусочек изоленты, который видимо был подложен этими мастерами. Отсюда делаю вывод что собирать компьютер лучше собственноручно. Ну и по делу: знакомый мастер подточил выступающую площадку и на всякий случай нанес небольшой слой лака, чтоб уж наверняка не закоротило, хотя расстояние теперь до ножек конденсатора более-менее приличное.